# Collecting routing information from RIPE?

Tags: domain-name-system, unix, router, static-routes

I would like a way of collecting ip blocks for known networks in the RIPE database. Take this search result as an example: http://www.db.ripe.net/whois?form_type=simple&full_query_string=&searchtext=AS-AKAMAI&do_search=Search
Here's all the networks for Akamai listed, I would like to be able to have my own static route to the network members listed in the result through a specific gateway on my local network.
This have to be able to run on Linux and/or *BSD.

Creating a custom script which queries whois servers on an interval sounds wrong.
**Is there a standardized way of collecting routes from the RIPE database?**

Comment: What does querying DNS have to do with collecting routing information?

Comment: @joeqwerty Nothing indeed, corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My knowledge of BGP and routes and how to query RIPE's WHOIS database and whatnot is very limited, but http://www.isc.org/software/irrtoolset sounds like it might be relevant. I compiled it on my machine and managed to produce the following:

```
~$ echo '@rtconfig networks AS39836' | rtconfig
!
network 84.53.147.0 mask 255.255.255.0
network 84.53.172.0 mask 255.255.255.0
network 84.53.147.0 mask 255.255.255.0
```

AS39836 is just a random AS from the "AS-AKAMAI" as-set, per your example.

From rtconfig's manfile:

```
@rtconfig networks <ASN-1>
    <ASN-1> is an AS number preceded with string "AS".  For each route registered with  
    origin <ASN-1>, a network statement of the form  "network <prefix> mask <mask>"
    is generated.
```

I suppose you could then do something ugly like this:

```
whois -h whois.ripe.net -x AS-AKAMAI | egrep '^members: +AS' | awk '{print $2;}' | while read member; do echo @rtconfig networks $member | rtconfig; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this FAQ](http://www.ripe.net/info/faq/projects/ris.html), it could help.

Comment: Interesting FAQ but I don't understand how to use that information practically to solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

You can [download a dump from RIPE](http://www.ripe.net/info/faq/db/main.html#17)